# Misunderstanding of classes in python, accessing and changing instance variables

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, instance

I am trying to change the instance variable, var3, associated with an instantiated object of Class3. I want to make this change by passing the instance variable, var3, to methods of another class (see code below).

I instantiate Class2 and Class3 in Class1's **init**, yielding the objects self.class2, self.class3.

Then I send the instance variable self.class3.var3 to a method (change_class3_var) defined in Class2, which appends a string to var3.

But when I go to print the instance variable, var3 (class1.class3.var3), the variable does not change as expected, it has not been appended to and remains just "class3" (instead of "class3 appended by class2".

I am looking for different answers along the lines of:

1. Why this doesn't work
2. Why this code style is a bad idea and what you think is the best alternative for achieving this behavior of fluidly passing/altering instance variables among various classes

This code is not used for anything critical, I am just trying to further my understanding. The idea is to use a base class (Class1) to glue all the classes together in a PyQt application, passing and changing instance variables fluidly using a collection of instantiated classes objects.

Thank you!!

```
class Class1:
    var = "class1"

    def __init__(self):
        self.class2 = Class2()
        self.class3 = Class3()

    def class2_to_class3(self):
        self.class2.change_class3_var(self.class3.var3)


class Class2:
    var2 = "class2"

    def change_class3_var(self, instance_var):
        instance_var += " appended by class2"
        print(instance_var)


class Class3:
    var3 = "class3"


class1 = Class1()

class1.class2_to_class3()

print(class1.class3.var3)
```

Writing code like this works as desired, but I may not always want to use a static or class method decorator (see below), i.e., I may want to, within the same method, use the instance self.

```
class Class1:
    var = "class1"

    def class2_to_class3(self):
        Class2.from_class3(Class3)


class Class2:
    var2 = "class2"

    @staticmethod
    def from_class3(cls):
        cls.var3 += " appended by class2"
        print(cls.var3)
        return


class Class3:
    var3 = "class3"

    def hello(self):
        print("hello from class 3")


class1 = Class1()

class1.class2_to_class3()

print(Class3.var3)
```

This also works, but I don't exactly like the way the classes are instantiated "outside" Class1. Also, I dont like the fact that if I ask VScode to go to the definition to var3 from within def from_cass3, that it cant zoom to the location of var 3 because it is looking for instance.var3 instead of class3.var3.

```
class Class1:
    var = "class1"

    def class2_to_class3(self):
        class2.from_class3(class3)


class Class2:
    var2 = "class2"

    def from_class3(self, instance):
        instance.var3 += " appended by class2"


class Class3:
    var3 = "class3"


class1 = Class1()
class2 = Class2()
class3 = Class3()

print(class3.var3)
class1.class2_to_class3()
print(class3.var3)
```

Comment: Hey Huapua, welcome to the site! You use the word "class" to describe both the classes themselves (e.g. `Class1`), and _objects_ made by instantiating those classes (e.g. `Class1()`). Can you please review your post and your code examples to clarify that? It's pretty hard to follow along right now

Comment: Yes, will try to clarify. It was hard for me to even try to explain, so I am not surprised it is hard to follow. Thanks

Comment: While it's perfectly fine to want to better understand things, right now your question has nothing to do with PyQt and it's mostly about object structure or membership because your example is too abstract (and also deals with strings, which are not mutable). If you *do* need this for a specific PyQt problem, I suggest you to take your time to [edit] your question and provide a *practical* example/explanation of how and/or why you need/want to do this. This is also important because if you're trying to do something like this with Qt objects (like widgets), it may become a problem, also because»

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know if it was a good idea on my part (maybe not), but I wanted to ask the general question, and not get into the weeds of PyQt, though my goal is to get this type of structure for PyQt. I will try to remove the pyqt tags. I would rather not discuss a practical application of this, other than I would like to learn new ways to better organize the code I write.

Comment: » you're arbitrarily trying to access instance and class attributes, and that should always be done with extreme care, because you *may* think you're accessing/writing an instance attribute while you aren't. Also, Python bindings for Qt use some "magic" under the hood to make Python work transparently with Qt (which has absolutely no awareness that you're using it from Python), and trying to change class attributes externally may give unexpected results. Modularity also means that objects should normally know *nothing* about other objects that are not its members. That's why we use signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, strings are immutable, meaning they can't be changed once they are created. In this part of your code:

> instance_var += " appended by class2"

you are adding the string to the local variable instance_var. Strings aren't the only immutable objects, tuples are as well (this is the difference between tuples and lists). Your attempt only works for mutable objects like lists. For immutable objects, since you cannot modify them in place, you need a way to update the reference in the original object.

As to why this is a bad idea, you are coupling your classes. This makes classes less modular and harder to maintain. You are also obscuring data flow, making it hard to track where data is modified. Good class design uses encapsulation, meaning each class is responsible for managing its own state.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I get what you are saying in your first point.

With respect to the 2nd point, I was thinking to use classes to organize code. For example, one class has the logic for serial communications of one instrument, another class has the logic for serial communications with another instrument, another class for multi-threading. It just seems intuitive to me to be able to pass objects between classes to get things working fluidly. Its hard for me to imagine another way to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes your thinking is correct. The issue is in the way the interaction happens. Instead of directly changing another classes state you can just invoke a method from that class which is responsible for changing its own state. You could,  in your example add a method in class3 called setVar3 which takes in a new string and it would work perfectly.  Or if the two classes need to share data you can implement a queue (which both classes can get a reference to in their constructors) and each class can modify and read from the queue as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, very appreciated advice. I tried to upvote your response but I don't have enough rep. I have been crawling this site for the last couple years since I started my journey learning how to code, and this is my first post.